# Why does my router not reply to ARP requests?

Tags: dns, arp

I am trying to test the ability for an embedded system to create DNS requests and process their replies, but I'm having problems getting those replies.

Physically, my embedded system `(192.168.1.50)` is connected to a switch, which is connected to a router `(192.168.1.1)`. I have another computer, `(192.168.1.31)` connected to the same switch, on which I have Wireshark running.

I'm trying to send a DNS request to Google's public DNS server `(8.8.8.8:53)` from my embedded system. Having done a bit of reading, I'm not surprised that this request is repackaged as an ARP request to the router - Wireshark reports a `who has 192.168.1.1? tell 192.168.1.50` message - but I receive no ARP reply from the router with its MAC address, which I think is what I'm expecting before the actual DNS request can be sent.

So, why is the router not replying?

I'm no network expert, so any simple help will be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think it is not replying?  The ARP request is broadcast, but the reply would be unicast.  Your computer running Wireshark should not see the reply.

Comment: Why don't you just replicate this DNS lookup on `192.168.1.31`?  YLearn is right, unless you're utilizing a hub or port-mirroring, you won't see a response.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So how can I see the reply? The only tools I currently have available are to step through with a debugger on the embedded platform (in which case I'm not really sure what I'm looking for) or Wireshark. Assume for a moment that the reply is being sent and I'm just not looking in the right place for it, what is the next thing I should be looking for, again, with these limited tools?

Comment: @EdKing, as Fizzle mentioned, you would need a hub or switch that allows port mirroring.  Aside from that, you could use a network tap, but to capture both directions with most of them, you would need a computer with two network interfaces.

Comment: What kind of switch are you using?  If its a Cisco switch, you cn enable port monitoring to capture the Arp reply.

Comment: I am using a Belkin switch (I can't remember the model). It looks like replicating the DNS lookup on `192.168.1.31` might be a good shout. I guess I would need some local DNS server running?

Comment: I have just rerun it and have set a breakpoint in the embedded system at the point at which an ARP reply would be received. This breakpoint is not hit, which I think shows that the router is not responding with its MAC. Incidentally, the router is a Linksys WRVS4400N, not a Belkin.

Comment: @EdKing Perhaps your embedded system isn't working as you would expect (I doubt the router is malfunctioning).  What is the source MAC address in the ARP request?

Comment: I have more information. I have been able to confirm that when an ARP reply is issued, my embedded system captures it. I did this by connecting `.50` directly to `.31` and issuing a DNS request to `.31` just to see the reply. As a further test, I put a second router downstream of the switch to have it acquire an IP from the main router at `.1`. Logging-in to the `.1` router, I see that it had allocated a WAN IP for the downstream one in its DHCP table but the downstream one never received it. Does this mean the `.1` router is having replies squashed by the switch?

Comment: @EdKing May I ask for a generalization of what this embedded system is?  If you **have** to see these responses from the system itself then I would imagine tcpdump is your best bet if it's available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. In fact, the reason that I was not able to receive ARP replies into my embedded system was because the switch was squashing them (I think this was because it was of a certain type). The solution was to place a downstream router of the switch and disable its firewall, thus creating another network within my LAN. I then requested the DNS server provided by the upstream router, through the downstream one. The downstream router does not squash ARP replies. To illustrate:

```
| NETWORK 1 -----------------------| NETWORK 2 --------------------|
| 192.168.1.50 --> 192.168.1.11   -|--> SWITCH --> 192.168.1.1    -|-->
| E.SYSTEM     --> DSTREAM ROUTER -|--> SWITCH --> USTREAM ROUTER -|-->
```

The upstream router knows a primary DNS server at `192.104.4.10`, so the request was formulated from the embedded system with these IP addresses:

```
IP:      192.168.1.50
Gateway: 192.168.1.11
Subnet:  255.255.255.0
DNS:     192.104.4.10
```

Thank you for the comments, they helped me to debug this.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't make much sense.  You are suggesting that a switch (which is designed to propagate ARP requests) is dropping ARP packets, and a router (which is designed to drop them) is passing them on.

Comment: As I've said, I'm no network expert, but without the second router, I don't get an ARP reply through the switch - neither from my embedded system or if I just plug a PC into it and `arping`. I do get an ARP reply if I move to another PC that doesn't go through this switch. The only way I could get my system to work was to use the downstream router.